# How to import python file (without class) to robot file

Tags: python, robotframework

My python file:

```
from libraries.Jpg import Jpg
def configure_jpg(jpg, ingress, egress, rep_factor=None):
    jpg_hd = Jpg(host=jpg)
    jpg_hd.inout_intf_rep_pair = ingress + ',1|' + egress + ',1'
    return jpg_hd.configure_jpg()
```

My robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Resource file for Jpg.
...            This resource file has the keywords that can be used to perform
...            operations on Jpg devices
Variables   terralogic.yaml
Library jpg_stout
Library Collections
Library BuiltIn

*** Test Cases ***
Configure Jpg
    ${info} =   Convert To Dictionary   ${t.resources.device0.system.primary}
    ${ip} = Get Variable Value  ${info['mgt-ip']}
    Configure Jpg   jpg=${ip}   ingress='ge-2/0/0'  egress='xe-4/2/6'
```

When I run the Robot file, the error `No keyword with name 'Configure Jpg' found.` occurs

Can a Robot file not import a python file without class? Please help me on this.

Comment: Does the above robot file actually give the error you say, and no other errors? You should be getting errors such as `Non-existing setting 'Library jpg_stout'.`

Comment: Can you check line  return jpg_hd.configure_jpg() in your library and see what it does, it seems to be a problem with that

Comment: Bryan, I got that error:
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/home/juniper/git/Toby/libraries/jpg_stout.robot': Importing test library 'jpg_stout' failed: ImportError: No module named 'jpg_stout'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None

Comment: Shijo, configure_jpg() works fine when called in Python code